# bulk update in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to update the list of users, In my controller I have returned the list of users

```
return View("usersList", user);
```

and In view I use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("usersList", "UserManagement"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model, "tbl_UserList");
}
```

and in editor template I use 'tbl_UserList.cshtml' as below

```
@model IList<tbl_Users>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Email)
    </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => item.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Email)
    </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<input id="subButton" type="submit" value="submit" title="submit data" />
}
```

and in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserList(List<tbl_Users> users)
{
    //..
}
```

here the users in controller is null, how can I solve this>
thanks

Comment: Show you `EditorTemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `EditorTemplate` to

```
@model tbl_Users
<tr>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)</td>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)</td>
</tr>
```

and rename it to `tbl_Users.cshtml`

Then in the main view

```
@model IList<tbl_Users>
@using (Html.BeginForm("usersList", "UserManagement"))
{
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>
        ....
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m); // do not specify a name
    </tbody>
  </table>
}
```

Note that you current `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which will not bind to a collection (inspect the html before and after to understand).

Comment: I added a for loop in 
<tbody>
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m); // do not specify a name
    </tbody>
 and it works

Comment: DO NOT add a loop! `Html.EditorFor()` takes `IEnumerable<T>` and is smart enough to render the collection properly with indexers. If you needed to add a loop, there are other errors in your code.

Comment: how can we use <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)</td>, when m is a List?

Comment: Because `DisplayNameFor()` has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<TModel>` - [refer documetation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833697%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) Note intellisense might complain at first but it will run. Using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[0].FirstName)` will throw an exception if there were no items in the collection so do not use it.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke If the entity list type is a ICollection, convert it to a List type. Because ICollection doesn't support indexing.
Example: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ToList()[0].FirstName)`

Comment: @AlparslanSARAL, NO! That does not work (and if you look at the html it generates you will see why). And using an `EditorTemplate` works fine with `ICollection<T>`. Using `IList<T>` is only required if using a `for` loop, but the model needs to be `IList<T>` so the expression is `m => m[0].FirstName`, not `m => m.ToList()[0].FirstName`